# Validation of Angular.JS directive being part of form

Tags: validation, angularjs, directive

I want to make my own Angular directive and use form validation on it. This will allow me to reuse this part of form in other places. The actual code is different, but I feel that I am thinking in wrong way here. First I made a form:

```
<form name="check1">
   <input name="first" ng-model="first" type="text" required> 
   <input name="second" ng-model="second" type="text" required> 
   <input name="third" ng-model="third" type="text" required> 
</form>
<span ng-show="check1.$invalid">Form is invalid</span>
```

The validation is working ok. Then I want my form to be similar to:

```
 <form name="check2">
   <input name="first" ng-model="first" type="text" required> 
   <mydirective second="second" third="third" required></mydirective>
</form>
<span ng-show="check2.$invalid">Form is invalid</span>
```

and JS :

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: 
        '<span>'+
        '<input name="second" ng-model="second" type="text" >'+
        '<input name="third" ng-model="third" type="text" >'+
        '</span>'
      ,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        second: '=',
        third: '='
    }
       }
});
```

What to do to make validation work ? Now filling "first" will make check2 form valid.

I have try to add link function to controller:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      controller.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue)
        console.log(viewValue);
         return viewValue;
      });
  }
```

but I got:

```
 TypeError: Cannot call method 'unshift' of undefined
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

It seems that my question was not fully well written. I was looking for possibility to conditionally "required" fields in Angular directive. So making:

```
<mydirective second="second" third="third" required></mydirective>
```

will make directive fields required, while this will not:

```
<mydirective second="second" third="third"></mydirective>
```

The solution is to use attrs in link function and ng-required. So:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
return {
    template: 
        '<span>'+
        '<input name="second" ng-model="second" type="text" ng-required="is_required">'+
        '<input name="third" ng-model="third" type="text" ng-required="is_required">'+
        '</span>'
      ,
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.is_required = angular.isDefined(iAttrs.required)
          }
       }
});
```

Comment: why are u setting up two way binding ?

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal: I want to initialize 'second' and 'third' in the scope of 'check2'. User will change their values in directive scope and once again in the scope of 'check2' they will be used (saved to server - not shown in this snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Just add "required" as attribute to your directive template code 
(it seems you forgot to do that, because in your first code snippet there is a "required" on each INPUT)
and everything will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for comment. The solution to my not well written question is in edit section.